# How to get back from InAppBrowser in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using [Inappbrowser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser) for payment gateway.

How to come back from InAppBrowser to our app after successfully done payment.

Comment: Which payment gateway are you using? See docs of related payment gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code.

```
browser.on('loadstart').subscribe((e) => {
     let compareURL = "https://myurl.com/folder_name/filename.php?CODE=XXXXX";
     console.log(e.url);
     if(e.url === compareURL){
       this.navCtrl.setRoot(ConfirmationPage, {
       orderId: this.orderId
     })
       browser.close();
       console.log('browser closed');
    }

    }, err => {
          console.error(err);
    });
```